Why does Hermione say that “Kreacher and Regulus’s family were all safer if they kept to the old pureblood line”?
I am reading Chapter 10 of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, and I don't understand this part:

“that Regulus changed his mind . . . but he doesn’t seem to have
explained that to Kreacher, does he? And I think I know why. Kreacher
and Regulus’s family were all safer if they kept to the old pure-blood
line. Regulus was trying to protect them all.”

What did Regulus's situation have to do with the old pureblood line? How was Regulus trying to protect his family by stealing the Horcrux?

"Line" as in "party line" not "blood line;" note that it's "pure-blood line" not "pure blood-line."

@DavidW yes I get its meaning. "Line" here is a lot of generations of a big family

Yeah. Following the pure-blood line means doing things like insulting muggles and spending time on genealogy.  If the family was noticed inviting Hermione's parents to dinner or anything else that pure-bloods didn't generally do, it would be "out of line" with purebloodery and put them in danger

oh, I understand: "Pure-blood line" means the assuming (thinking) that pure-blood is superior than all other types

Actually, @Dat, DavidW was explaining that line here is not the generations of a big family. Here, line is used to mean "the accepted position/opinion of the purebloods". See definition 4(a) here.

I think it's worth explaining (not sufficient to justify an answer) that the phrase is based on British slang which non-British readers may not be familiar with: 'that old party line', which refers to the cliche words and phrases a party might adopt (as in 'a line of dialogue'). So if a politicians says they'll 'lower taxes!', a British person might quip sarcastically 'oh, that old party line'. Essentially Regulus is parroting 'that old party line', the party line in question being the 'pure-blood' stuff.

Regulus wasn't trying to protect his family by stealing the Horcrux.
He was trying to protect his family despite stealing the Horcrux.
He didn't tell anyone he was no longer serving Voldemort.  If he had, it's likely that either (a) someone in his family would turn him in, or (b) when Voldemort found out, he'd kill the whole family, not just Regulus.
"...kept to the old pure-blood line..." is meant in the sense of "keep to the party line."  This means to hold to the standard belief of a group of people, usually one's in-group.
In this case, it means the standard beliefs of the purebloods, such as showing contempt for Muggle-borns, Muggles, lesser magical creatures, and so forth.  By keeping to the old pure-blood line, Regulus avoided giving any outward signs that he wasn't following Voldemort's ideology.

I understand that if Regulus didn't give any outward signs that he wasn't following Voldemort, his family would be safer. But I still try to figure out the literal meaning of "...kept to the old pure-blood line..."

Following the pure-blood line means doing things like insulting muggles and spending time on genealogy. If the family was noticed inviting Hermione's parents to dinner or anything else that pure-bloods didn't generally do, it would be "out of line" with purebloodery and put them in danger

@Dat It's not referring to heritage or bloodlines.  "Towing the party line" is a common English phrase for people who blindly follow whatever their ideology's dogma is.

@Ryan_L I thought it was "toeing" the party line, not "towing" it. Like "toeing" in the sense of how one would generally not step over some sort of official line.

@lieutenantZipp huh, I don't know now.  I thought it was "Towing" like you're pulling for the party.

That makes some sense, but I don't think it's so much pulling for them as it is committing to agreeing with them. You don't go past what they're saying, you just stand in a line agreeing.

I looked it up- it is "toeing", and seems to probably derive from military terminology about lining up for inspections or roll call or something.
